# How to make Mockito verify work with Enumeration

Tags: scala, unit-testing, enums, mockito

I have following error in a unit test:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
userService.registerPro(
    "newpro@gmail.com",
    "name",
    "name",
    "123",
    "test",
    "",
    List(),
    tier1,
    "encryptedpassword",
    inactive,
    0,
    List(POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1)))
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
userService.registerPro(
    "newpro@gmail.com",
    "name",
    "name",
    "123",
    "test",
    "",
    List(),
    tier1,
    "encryptedpassword",
    inactive,
    0,
    List(POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1)))
);
```

Although the message says that they are different, they'r actually identical. Note that, `tier1` and `inactive` are enum:

```
object UserSubscriptionTiers extends Enumeration {
  type UserSubscriptionTier = Value
  val TIER0 = Value("tier0") 
  val TIER1 = Value("tier1") 
  val TIER2 = Value("tier2") 
  val TIER3 = Value("tier3") 
  val TIERA = Value("tierA") 
}

object UserStatuses extends Enumeration{
  type UserStatus = Value
  def ACTIVE = Value("active")
  def INACTIVE = Value("inactive")
}
```

And it seem that mockito does not work properly with enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second enum should be using values instead of method definition:

```
object UserStatuses extends Enumeration{
  type UserStatus = Value
  val ACTIVE = Value("active")
  val INACTIVE = Value("inactive")
}
```

Changing from `def` to `val` should return the same instance over instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: I didn't even notice that I was using `def` for it. Thanks for pointing it out.